# Valid proof technique? finite-sample argument then convergence in probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let's consider a toy example: $x$ and $y$ are random (column) vectors for which the covariance matrices $\operatorname{Var}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(y)$ exist and are invertible. Then,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(y)\succeq\operatorname{Cov}(y,x)[\operatorname{Var}(x)]^{-1}\operatorname{Cov}(x,y)\tag{$*$}
$$
where $\succeq$ means the LHS matrix minus the RHS matrix is positive semidefinite and $\operatorname{Cov}(y,x)$, for example, is $E[(y-E(y))(x-E(x))']$.

($*$) is true and a proof, for instance, can be found in Tripathi (Economic Leters, 1999). **My question: is the following also a valid proof?**

> Let $\{X_i,Y_i\}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, be i.i.d. $\{x-E(x),y-E(y)\}$. Let $X$ be the random matrix with rows $X_1',X_2',\ldots,X_n'$ and let $Y$ be formed similarly. Then, as $n\to\infty$,
>   $$
> X'X/n\overset{\text{P}}{\to}\operatorname{Var}(x),\quad Y'Y/n\overset{\text{P}}{\to}\operatorname{Var}(y),\quad X'Y/n\overset{\text{P}}{\to}\operatorname{Cov}(x,y)
> $$
>   where $\overset{\text{P}}{\to}$ means convergence in probability. But for each finite $n$,
>   $$
> Y'Y/n-(Y'X/n)(X'X/n)^{-1}(X'Y/n)=\frac{1}{n}Y'[I_n-X(X'X)^{-1}X']Y\succeq 0\tag{$**$}
> $$
>   because the expression in the square brackets on the RHS above is an orthogonal projection matrix. So ($*$) holds by using ($**$) and letting $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, we can reduce this problem to scalars via quadratic forms. Let $Z_n\to^p c$ and $Z_n \geq 0$ a.s. Suppose $c < 0$. Then $c + \varepsilon <0$ for small enough $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $P(|Z_n - c| < \varepsilon) \leq P(Z_n < c+ \varepsilon) \leq P(Z_n < 0) = 0$. Take limits to see that the first probability converges to 1, a contradiction. So I'd say this proof is valid if you think the preceding argument is obvious.

Comment: @Galton Thanks. Your example is clear to me. If you turn your assertion about the validity of my proof's technique into an answer, I'll accept (after a bit further delay to see if there's some other feedback.).